# Unsupported format character?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to print a line with a with a float formatter to 2 decimal points like this:

```
    print "You have a discount of 20% and the final cost of the item is'%.2f' dollars." % price
```

But when I do I get this error:

ValueError: unsupported format character 'a' (0x61) at index 27

What does this mean and how can I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 5):

The issue is your `20%`, Python is reading `...20% and...` as `"% a" % price` and it doesn't recognize `%a` as a format.

You can use `20%%` as @Anand points out, or you can use string [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
>>> price = 29.99
>>> print "You have a discount of 20% and the final cost of the item is {:.2f} dollars.".format(price)
You have a discount of 20% and the final cost of the item is 29.99 dollars.
```

Here the `:.2f` gives you 2 decimal places as with `%.2f`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is with the single `%` sign after `20` , python maybe thinking it is a format specifier.

Try this -

```
print "You have a discount of 20%% and the final cost of the item is'%.2f' dollars." % price
```

Comment: Thx, my program is up and running now

Answer (score 0):

The `%` operator on strings treats its left operand as a format specifier. All `%` signs in it will be treated specially.

But the `%` after the `20` is not intended as such and thus must be escaped properly: write `20%%`. This tells the format specifier processing routine to treat it as a literal `%`.

Or, as Scott wrote, use the newer `.format()` stuff.